# How do I negate this if/else comparison to just if?

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm trying to set the class hidden, unless two factors are met. Currently, I'm using the code below:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['prerequisite']) && $form == "CheckingIn")
{

}
else
{
    echo "hidden";
}
?>
```

How can I fix this to just be an if statement instead of an if/else?

Comment: Aren't ternary operators equivalent to If / Then statements?

Comment: You are using an if/else, but no code for the if. In VB, you would do `If <condition> Then Else <code> End If`. There is still a Then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Negate the expression; use the **"NOT"** logical operator:

```
if (!(isset($_POST['prerequisite']) && $form == "CheckingIn")) { echo "hidden"; }
```

(notice the **!** symbol)

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @chris Maybe also show how to do it using a Ternary Operator?

Comment: Negation as failure is the most optimal solution

Comment: @RichardA Actually is a good idea in order to make this question more generic and complete, but I think he would need to change the question a little bit, so a ternary explanation fits here. (The question is only about doing the `else` without the `then`, not about choosing among two options)

Comment: @BowenCheng : like this probably: http://codepad.org/xiCEg1r1

Comment: @chris, is that the same as `if (!(isset($_POST['prerequisite']) && $form == "CheckingIn")) { echo "hidden"; }`? It's acting the same though. Gosh, logic is so confusing, even when broken down to a logic table.

Comment: @BowenCheng well, in your other example, you had '`ApartmentsCheckingOut`' instead of `CheckingIn`. To make it less confusing, try to read it out loud. For instance, `if (!(isset($_POST['prerequisite']) && $form == "CheckingIn")) {` could be read as *"if is **not true** that `$_POST['prerequisite']` is set and `$form` equals `CheckingIn`, then...."*