# php: I need the OPPOSITE of this please...?

Tags: php

The following searches the string $fruit for any of the words apples, oranges and bananas and acts accordingly:

```
if ((stristr($fruit,'apples')) || (stristr($fruit,'oranges')) || (stristr($fruit,'bananas')) !== false) {//some code }
```

I need the OPPOSITE. I need code to run if the string $fruit does NOT have any of the three. I was thinking something like

```
if not ((stristr($fruit,'apples')) || (stristr($fruit,'oranges')) || (stristr($fruit,'bananas')) !== false) {//some code }
```

but that doesnt seem to work...

A little hand holding please? Thanks...

Comment: May b u can also try this 

`if (!(((stristr($fruit,'apples')) || (stristr($fruit,'oranges')) || (stristr($fruit,'bananas')))) 
{//some code }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I negate this if/else comparison to just if?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247639/how-do-i-negate-this-if-else-comparison-to-just-if)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.
>
> The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations.

Try:

```
if ( stristr($fruit, 'apples') === FALSE && stristr($fruit,'oranges') === FALSE &&  stristr($fruit,'bananas') === FALSE) {
    // some code
}
```

Since `stristr` only returns a string or FALSE, this code can be simplifed to:

```
if ( !stristr($fruit, 'apples') && !stristr($fruit,'oranges') &&  !stristr($fruit,'bananas')) {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone.

I ending up doing this, based on all input from those that replied, which worked:

```
if (!((stristr($fruit,'apples')) || (stristr($fruit,'oranges')) || (stristr($fruit,'bananas')) !== false))
```

Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

```
if (!(stristr($fruit,'apples')) || !(stristr($fruit,'oranges')) || !(stristr($fruit,'bananas')) !== false) {//some code }
```